# NEON Overflow detection

Tags: arm, overflow, neon

I have a long loop where neon vector additions are performed on 8 bit elements. The problem is that after a while it is almost sure that some or all the vector components are saturated because of overflow. Is there a fast way to detect this so that I can flush the results, zero the vector and continue? I already tried by checking the C and V flags but it seems neon operations don't set them.

edit: here is the code of interest, a little simplified. Also, I upgraded to 16 bit, but it will still overflow

```
int16x8_t Sum;
for(int C = 0; C < 100; C++)
{
    // Sum += |a - b|
    Sum = vabaq_u16(
      Sum,                      
      vld1q_u16((uint16_t *)a),
      vld1q_u16((uint16_t *)b)
    );
}
```

Comment: it would probably be helpful if you show some code so people can see exactly what you mean

Comment: I take it the 100-item count one is of the simplifications? I don't see how you could possibly overflow 16 bits accumulating 8-bit values otherwise (65535 / 255 = 257 > 100).

Comment: Also, the pointer cast in `vld1q_u16((uint16_t *)a)` looks very suspicious - what type is `a`? If it's still an array of 8-bit data then this code is totally broken.

Comment: Yes, it is a simplification, and yes, there was a problem with a. a is 16 bit, but it is signed, now I'm using vld1q_s16 and (int16_t*)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`VQADD`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1361289975719.html) for the summation, not only will it saturate (clamp) the values instead of overflowing and wrapping around (which may be desirable in itself), but it will also set the saturation flag (bit 27) in the FPSCR whenever that happens. Once set, that flag needs to be cleared manually by writing back the FPSCR value with bit 27 zeroed.

A possible alternative, depending on exactly how the rest of the algorithm uses the result, might be to split your accumulator across two registers and use a widening operation ([`VABAL`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1361289938635.html)) on each half of the input vectors to accumulate 16-bit elements, then you can simply flush the result at a predetermined interval without ever needing to explicitly check. Since the minimum number of unsigned 8-bit values required to overflow a 16-bit accumulator is 258 (65535/255 = 257), then if the loop flushes the result every 257 or fewer iterations overflow becomes impossible.

Comment: Ok I edited the question adding some code.
I shall investigate to check whether vabaq uses vqadd to accumulate the results or not. If it doesn't, I may create my own intrinsic, probably with vaba and vqadd, but I still need to make some research about it.

Comment: You could still use the widening approach with a pair of `vabal` intrinsics. Come to think of it, that way you wouldn't actually need to waste time _checking_ for overflow - just flush the result vectors after every 256 iterations or so and you can _guarantee_ it never happens.